# How can show parents name on Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

How can show parents name on Yii2.

This is my work-

I want to show state name which is situated state id like as 1, District is child table name, where is foreign key state_id, i want to replace state_name where is situated state_id.

This is my sql-

```
CREATE TABLE district (
district _id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
state_id int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'FK',
district_name varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (district _id),
FOREIGN KEY (state_id) REFERENCES state (state_id)
);
```

[image: This is my work- i want to show state name which is situated state id like as 1]

My controller-

```
$district= District::find()->all();
```

View-

```
<?php
foreach($district as $districtt)
{
?>
<tr>
<td><?= $districtt->state_id ?></td>
<td><?= $districtt->districtt_name ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: add some code of your trial.

Comment: instead of state you went to show state name? Am i right?

Comment: use relation to  show `state_name`.

Comment: Yes exactly   **Ishan Shah**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class District extends ActiveRecord
// ...
public function getState()
{
    return $this->hasOne(State::className(), ['id' => 'state_id']);
}
```

**index.php**

```
<?php foreach(District::find()->all() as $district) { ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?= $district->state ? $district->state->state_name : $district->state_id ?></td>
      <td><?= $district->district_name ?></td>
    </tr>
```